# Aurelia not displaying correct representation of array after removing item

Tags: data-binding, aurelia

I have a list of items in an array.

When i click the item in my view i am attempting to remove this item

## View

```
<div class="lootItem" repeat.for="lootItem of stack">
    <div class="noselect" click.delegate="$parent.takeItem(lootItem)">
         <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> ${lootItem.value}
    </div>
</div>
```

## ViewModel

```
takeItem(lootItem){
    this.eventAggregator.publish(new ItemTaken(lootItem));
    console.log(_.includes(this.stack, lootItem)); //true
    
    _.pull(this.stack, lootItem); //removes item and fails to update the ui
    _.remove(this.stack, lootItem); //removes item and fails to update the ui
    this.stack.shift(); //removes first item and updates the ui
}
```

Both `.pull()` and `.remove()` (using lodash) will remove the item in the array but not update the ui.

`.shift()` manages to remove an item from the array and is updating the UI.

Why is Aurelia not updating the UI despite me removing the item when using lodash?

addendum: it might be worth noting if i click the same item twice then `_.includes` is true the first time and then false the second time.

Comment: Why are you using lodash when ES2015 has this functionality built in? Use the native functions and your code will work.

Comment: I am familiar with a lot of the lodash methods which is why i decided to bring it in, does that mean manipulating the array outside of the standard ES methods will not work? For now it seems i can use filter and manipulate the array like so: `this.stack = this.stack.filter(item => item != lootItem);`. However I feel it's not as clear as a simple `.remove()` would be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of lodash, but I've posted an answer that shows how simple it is to use the built-in array methods. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia can provide you with the index of the current item when inside a repeater using the `$index` variable. Then, simply use the built in array methods that ES2015 provides:

## View

```
<div class="lootItem" repeat.for="lootItem of stack">
    <div class="noselect" click.delegate="$parent.takeItem($index, lootItem)">
         <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> ${lootItem.value}
    </div>
</div>
```

## ViewModel

```
takeItem($index, lootItem){
    this.eventAggregator.publish(new ItemTaken(lootItem));

    this.stack.splice($index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using ES2015 Sets Yet another approach is to use the ES2015 Set data
> structure. It can be initialized with an array of values, and the Set
> prototype even provides a delete method for removing a specific value
>
> ...
>
> However, the semantics of sets are different from regular arrays. By
> definition, a set is a collection of unique values. Therefore, it
> never contains duplicates. If you need a collection that allows for
> duplicate values, sets are the wrong data structure.
>
> https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/07/16/removing-elements-from-javascript-arrays

I am now using a Set for this and it allows me to use `.add()` and `.delete()`. I just need to remember that everything has to be unique (okay in my case here)

I'd still like to understand why manipulating the array though lodash doesn't work but i'll investigate that some other time.

---

Addendum

You can also use a prototype:

```
interface Array<T> {
   remove(itemToRemove: T): Array<T>;
}

(<any>Array.prototype).remove = function (itemToRemove) {
    const index = this.indexOf(itemToRemove);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the scope of the variables.

_.pull and _.remove are returning a new instance of an array.

Try

`this.stack = _.remove(this.stack, lootItem);`

Comment: According the documentation it should mutate the array, inspecting the variables show it has actually removed the item but it is not reflected in the view.